# How to allocate memory for char strings in a struct array?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am about to create a programm which stores data of students in a list.
My question is, how to shall I allocate memory for each char string in my struct array. 
My code is down below. If there're some other mistakes, please correct me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DATA 10;
#define NAME 10;

typedef struct{
int id;
char *givenname;
char *familyname;

} students;

int main()
{
int answer;
int incr = 0; // Index for students in the list
int datalen = DATA;
int namelen = NAME;

students *studentlist;
studentlist = malloc(datalen * sizeof(students)); // Allocate memory for first ten students

if(NULL == studentlist){
    printf("Error: Couldn't allocate memory\n");
    exit(0);
}

for(incr = 0; incr < datalen; incr ++){
    printf("Add student to the list? Yes(1) No(2)\n");
    scanf("%d", &answer);

    if(answer != 1){
        break;
    }

    studentlist[incr]->givenname = malloc(namelen * sizeof(char)); // Allocate memory for each name
    studentlist[incr]->familyname = malloc(namelen * sizeof(char));

    printf("Insert ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &studentlist[incr].id);

    printf("Insert given name: \n");
    scanf("%s", studentlist[incr].givenname);

    printf("Insert family name: \n");
    scanf("%s", studentlist[incr].familyname);


}

free(studentlist);
free(studentlist.givename);
free(studentlist.familyname);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: The way you are allocating the memory looks ok. Do you have a specific problem? The way you free it is wrong ...

Comment: `studentlist[incr]->givenname` --> `studentlist[incr].givenname`

Comment: 1. Don't forget space for a 0 terminator. 2. free `studentlist.givename` (and familyname) before `studentlist` or else you're invoking undefined behaviour (accessing freed memory). 3. Infact how can you free studentlist then access by `.`? If you freed it it ,must be a pointer and so access via `->`. - Does this even compile?

Comment: `free(studentlist.givename);` --> do each element `free(studentlist[incr].givename);` and before `free(studentlist);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference of some elements is wrong:

```
studentlist[incr]->givenname
```

It should be:

```
studentlist[incr].givenname
```

Allocation of strings seems fine.

Your freeing code needs change:

```
free(studentlist);
free(studentlist.givename);
free(studentlist.familyname);
```

You need to free studentlist.givename and studentlist.familyname in a loop and then free studentlist at the end:

```
for(incr = 0; incr < datalen; incr ++){
   free(studentlist[incr].givename);
   free(studentlist[incr].familyname);
}
free(studentlist);
```